# How to solve inhomogeneous quadratic forms in integers?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

If I have a quadratic form like $y^2 - x^2 - x = k$ none of the techniques I know work because of the nasty $x$. Note that homogenizing doesn't work because a solution of $Y^2 - X^2 - X Z = k Z^{(2)}$ does not lead to a solution of the original equation in integers, at least as far as I have been able to determine.

How does one understand the solution set of these equation? How can I solve them?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1050570_

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Over 200 years ago Lagrange solved the general binary quadratic Diophatine equation

$$\rm a\ x^2 + b\ xy + c\ y^2 + d\ x + e\ y + f = 0 $$

It reduces to a Pell equation: put $\rm\ D = b^2-4ac,\ E = bd-2ae,\ F = d^2-4af\:.\ $ Then

$$\rm  D\ Y^2\ =\ (D\ y + E)^2 + D\ F - E^2,\quad\quad Y\ =\ 2ax + by + d $$

Therefore if we put $\rm\quad\ \ X = D\ y + E,\quad\ \ N = E^2 - D\ F\quad\ \ $ we have the Pell equation

$$\rm X^2 - D\ Y^2\ =\ N $$

Dario Alpern has a web page [Quadratic two integer variable equation solver](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM) that will solve any such equation - with complete descriptions of the methods involved. For some  recent optimizations of Lagrange's algorithm see this paper H. C. Williams et al. [A new look at an old equation.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-79456-1_2)

Comment: In particular, consider the equation
\begin{equation}
4a(b^2-4ac)(ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f) = 0,
\end{equation}
where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are arbitrary. As long as $a(b^2-4ac) \ne 0$, we can assume $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$, and we have the Pell equation
\begin{align*}
 \bigl((b^2-4ac)y-2ae+bd\bigr)^2 - (b^2-4ac)(2ax+by+d)^2
  &= 4a(ae^2+b^2f+cd^2-bde-4acf).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 6):

These all reduce to equations
$$f(x,y)=k$$
where $x$ and $y$ are integers, possibly satisfying some
congruence conditions, and $f$ is a homogeneous
quadratic form. In two variables this basically
comes down to solving norm equations in the rings
of integers in quadratic fields.
For your example you get
$$4y^2-4x^2-4x-1=4k-1$$
that is
$$y'^2-x'^2=4k-1$$
where $x'=2x-1$ is odd and $y'=2y$ is even. This is atypically
easy, since it factorizes as $(y'-x')(y'+x')=4k-1$. More typically
you'd get a Pell-type equation.

Comment: "atypically easy" - :D

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Why/how would I get $4y^2-4x^4-4x-1=4k-1$!

Comment: @muad: multiply by 4 and subtract 1 from both sides.  That lets you factor 4x^2 + 4x + 1 to get rid of the linear term.