# Squaring an integer quadratic

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $Q(p)=37p^2-47p+4$. How does one go about finding all primes $p$ such that $Q(p)$ is a square of an integer?

*A bonus question.*  Is there a regular method to construct integer triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $Q(p)=ap^2+bp+c$ is a square for a finite number of primes?

Comment: Yes, $a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=0$. Then $Q(p)=(p+1)^2-1$ is square for only finitely many $p$.

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: @Will Jagy: Call it a random exercise from a problem book.

Comment: in that case, have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Diophantine equation $n^2=37p^2-47p+4$ can be solved, as can be all binary quadratic Diophanite equations, see 
[How to solve inhomogeneous quadratic forms in integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/how-to-solve-inhomogeneous-quadratic-forms-in-integers).
In your case, start with $p=3,23,...$.