# Enumerating integer solutions to quadratic equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Consider a quadratic equation with integer coefficients in two variables.

$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$

I would like to know how to find the number of integer solutions $(x,y)$ to this equations.
Is there some closed formula?

Comment: I know of a step by step method to solve specific ones. Have never been able to use it to get a general solution though.

Comment: See <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/how-to-solve-inhomogeneous-quadratic-forms-in-integers?rq=1> for details.