# Numbers $N$ that satisfy $N^2 - N = 2a^2 + 2a$ for some integer $a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find integers $N$ that satisfy the following relationship:

$$N^2 - N = 2a^2 + 2a$$

for some integer $a$. I have computationally verified that such numbers do exist. But finding large values of such $N$ is computationally expensive. It feels like this is a simple undergrad discrete math problem, but I am having an unusally hard time finding solutions to this.

Comment: An affine change of variables transforms this equation into a Pell equation. See also https://oeis.org/A046090, https://oeis.org/A053141

Comment: There are simple algorithms for such, e.g. see the Alpertron web page linked in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9288/242), and choose "Show steps".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want $n$ and $a$ positive:

$$     (2n-1)^2  - 2 (2a+1)^2 = -1           $$
The values of $2n-1$ are in the sequence  $1, 7, 41, 239, 1393, 8119,$  with rule  $s_{j+2}  = 6 s_{j+1}  - s_j.$
So the values of $n$   are $1, 4, 21, 120, 697$  with rule $$n_{j+2} = 6 n_{j+1} - n_j -2.$$

The values for $a$ are $0,2,14, 84, 492, 2870,$  and obey
$$a_{j+2} = 6 a_{j+1} - a_j +2.$$